# Possible to have a sticky section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not sure if it's possible with StackExchange's current UI/model, but do you think it would be helpful for both new users and or existing users to have a list of common websites such as the Salesforce API Doc, Visualforce Page Docs, APEX Docs, Server Status (Trust Site), etc off on the side bar to the right?

That being said, if possible, do you think having a section of undocumented features would be nice to sticky as well? One thing I could think of are URL Parameters Salesforce currently supports but there's no documentation on their sites such as saveURL, retURL, clone, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify one thing - the URL parameters is unsupported, not just undocumented. The product managers have always taken the position that you shouldn't use it as it may be removed without warning.

Comment: which is understandable, there just has to be an `advisory` stating that it could go away at anytime, but it does help one possibly develop buttons while avoiding the use of creating a VF/APEX if possible.

Answer (score 4):

I think the common web sites are known by those with any kind of experience. There are others who simply don't want to go and look at the documentation, or don't want to run a search for what they need that's in it. So would it be useful? I don't think it would be the best use of the space, nor do I think it would be used. Perhaps having one link to [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&select_subject%5B%5D=Force.com&select_type=&filter_text=&commit=FILTER%20RESULTS) where the rest can be easily be located from *might* be of use, but even then, I feel that anyone who's serious about developing for this platform ought to become familiar with where the latest docs can be found.

Now, I do like your idea when it comes to undocumented features! However, I suspect that within the StackExchange model, the best way to do that is to create a community wiki by starting a post and letting those with the knowledge respond and contribute their expertise to it.

Comment: I can see your point in regards to the documentations, I just something for that place holder, instead of that if there's a push against it, it can link to salesforce cookbook section as well. It doesn't have to be limited just to documentation.

Comment: Stack Exchange is set up to generate related content when someone asks a question on a topic. I don't know if it's possible for the documentation to come up at the top of the list. I presume they want to keep visitors here. So again, perhaps a wiki post with how to find docs related to the subject or *tag(s)* might be the only way to get what you're suggesting to come up as related content. If people also refer users to those posts, they come in handy as boilerplate or references.

Answer (score 4):

I understand why it might be useful, but I don't think that there needs to be an overall set of links.

The tag and tag wiki features allow that information to provided at the specific level it is needed.  Anyone can create tags and edit their wikis. Depending on rep, the edit may be subject to approval.

For example, there is an [apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex) tag wiki (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/apex/info) that does have links to external sources such as the Apex Developer's Guide.

There's no tag hierarchy, but an undocumented-feature tag along with something more specific like url-hacking might not be bad. It'd be similar to how there is a general apex tag and many questions that are tagged with it are also tagged with more specific tags.

I could also see community wiki Q&A's for stuff like top learning sites, etc. Like this [Getting Started with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell/1016986#1016986).

So, I think that the combination of tag wikis and community wikis can work.

Comment: Are you suggesting or implying that a tag and/or wiki could be created for undocumented/unsupported features and perhaps others like "how to find docs to related subjects", etc that had more specific links, provided someone wanted to make the effort to create them. The benefit being that links to those wikis could then serve as "canned responses" to commonly asked questions. If so, I think that's what many of us have been looking for to help handle the flood of unresearched questions.

Comment: I was thinking of classifying the questions with the tags and supplying good wikis on them. There's no tag hierarchy, but an undocumented-feature tag along with something more specific like url-hacking might not be bad. It'd be similar to how there is a general apex tag and many questions that are tagged with it are also tagged with more specific tags. I could also see community wiki Q&A's for stuff like top learning sites, etc. Like this [Getting Started with Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell/1016986#1016986)

Comment: Excellent! Very well thought out Peter. I recommend you edit your original post above to add that comment and perhaps expand on those thoughts. I think that would be VERY useful. Its takes what I had in mind when I posted my response to the "next level" and organizes it in a very useful manner. Some great Blogs come to mind for learning sites that I've often gone to as I've learned SF. I truly like what you've posted. I'd give you an extra vote if I could. :)