# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/design-for-salesforce-stack-exchange) and patience.

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

[Main site favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/salesforce/img/favicon.ico)

[Meta site favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/salesforcemeta/img/favicon.ico)

We have also updated the themes for the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16893/salesforce-discussions), [twitter](https://twitter.com/stacksalesforce) account and email newsletter template for this site.

I'd be happy to tweak the design post launch. There was some feedback about the header background color. I'd like to see after a week or so, if people still feel strongly about it.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a **new post** here on Meta and tag it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community! I really appreciate all the help you provided during this design process!

Comment: is the mobile site also getting the updates ?

Comment: Thanks for the good job @Jin!

Comment: @Jin, really looks great!

Comment: I had to come back and let you know @Jin the new design is fantastic! I thoroughly enjoy the aesthetics (fonts, colors, etc). The synergy with Salesforce1 Style Guide really makes me feel that SFSE is a real extension of the Salesforce ecosystem. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

So glad to see this go live! It's been 2 years, 8 months and 5 days since I first put in the proposal.

Got to say, I absolutely love the cloud shaped badges!

Comment: I love the cloud shaped badges too...

Answer (score 9):

Awesome job, Jin - great to not see that 'beta' label :-)

Answer (score 5):

> And we're out of beta.
>   We're releasing on time.
>   [Portal - 'Still Alive'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6ljFaKRTrI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m34s)

[image]

Source: [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce)

Comment: Now about that Half-Life 3...

Comment: @eyescream Sorry, that would be off-topic. Try [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life) :P

Comment: 'Still Alive' nice one :D

Answer (score 0):

Awesome Design. I am in love with cloud shaped badges.

Answer (score 0):

Looks great on good monitor, not so much on cheap Dell - contrast is too low.

Comment: Don't use cheap dells? :P

Comment: Oh how I wish I could Mr Cat. Isn't it ironic that your home entertainment computer is multiple times better than work machine?

Comment: Yes. (yesyesyesy)